# Preview the command formed by find -exec

Tags: find

I'm trying to execute a command repeatedly on every LOL file in a directory and have the output share the base name. My first thought is `find . -type f -iname '*.lol' -exec command {} {}.out \:` I know this will result in a lot of lol.out files, but I can rename those in a second step. The problem I'm having is that the command is failing on every file, although I can manually type it in successfully. I would like to debug my metacommand, but I don't know how to see the command that is actually being executed. Is there a way to get find to generate the list of commands it intends to execute?

Comment: you could maybe place an echo in the command handed off to `-exec`

Comment: That did it! Simple answers are always the best.

Comment: Is this another meaning of LOL?

Comment: I assume it's just a typo but your `-exec` must end with a quoted semicolon `;` not colon `:`

Answer (score 8):

Use `-ok` in place of `-exec`.  This displays the command that `find` is about to run and will ask for confirmation.  The `-ok` flag is in every other way exactly equal to the `-exec` flag.

The command is not executed if anything other than `y` is given at the confirmation prompt.

Comment: I can see where that would be necessary for destructive commands.

Comment: @user212803 ... or just any command that you need to get right.