# Find -exec dry run?

Tags: find, exec

Is there a way to see what the result of a `find . -exec somecommand {} \;` would be with substitutions, without actually running the commands? Like a dry run (or test run or print)?

For example, suppose I have the following file structure:

```
/a/1.txt
/a/2.txt
/a/b/3.txt
```

Is there a way to test `find . type f -exec rm {} \;` from within the `a` directory such that the output would printed to stdout but not executed such as:

```
rm 1.txt
rm 2.txt
rm b/3.txt
```

**Update**
Note: `rm` is just an example command, I'm interested in the general case

Comment: Isn't this just basically the output of find, with your command prepended?

Comment: In the most general case, this is not possible as the code executed by `-exec` may well affect the pathnames found by `find`.  Thus, doing a "dry run" would potentially find _different_ files from when running for real.  Note that `-exec` acts like a test, just like `-name`, so if the `-exec` code returns _false_, the next stage is not executed for this pathname.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preview the command formed by find -exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340593/preview-the-command-formed-by-find-exec)

Comment: @muru no it doesn't.

Comment: @User ...it doesn't? How are the questions different? (If they're _not_ the same, that means I've probably misunderstood this one).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The difference could possibly be that this question asks to dry-run, whereas the other asks about previewing (and then, probably, executing) the command. But it's unclear as the user here does not say how exactly they want to deal with commands with side effects affecting the process of finding files.

Comment: I'd need an explanation of what the user is looking for in a "dry run" that isn't there in a "preview" before that distinction made sense to me. In my experience those things are synonymous -- one performs a dry run to preview what an operation would do without actually doing it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can run `echo rm` instead of `rm`

```
find . type f -exec echo rm {} \;
```

Also, `find` has `-delete` option to delete files it finds

Comment: Minor point: beware of  man echo  since that will document /bin/echo, while in many cases simply running  echo  will use code embedded in the shell which might have subtle differences.

Comment: However find will use /bin/echo as find is not part of the shell

Comment: This is not an accurate printout of what the command would run. For example, if you have a file named `two words.txt`, `echo` doesn't let you distinguish whether it's one file named `two` and a second one `words.txt`

Comment: The OP only asked to "_see what the result [...] would be_", not to need to be able to copy'n'paste or otherwise repeat it precisely, @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @roaima, but if your result isn't precise, you aren't _really_ seeing the result. You're seeing a different, corrupted result, and misinterpreting the result can mean being unaware of bugs in the code one is trying to test.

Answer (score 3):

For `rm` specifically, you don't need `-exec`: simply run `find . -type f` to list, and add `-delete` to delete the files listed by the previous command (obviously barring any matching files being created/deleted in the meantime).

Also, for commands like `rm` which take an arbitrary number of arguments you'll want to replace `\;` with `+` to run as few commands as possible.

Comment: You haven't actually answered the question here, which is asking about how to do a dry run.

Comment: `-delete` is nonstandard and may not be supported by whatever version of `find` you are using.

Comment: @djsmiley2kStaysInside This answer is specifically about the original case, removing files.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a mouthful, but unlike approaches using `echo`, the below outputs code you could run in your shell without any changes to have the correct result, even when your filenames contain quotes, spaces, shell metacharacters, etc.

```
printcmd() { printf '%q ' "$@"; printf '\n'; }

find . -exec bash -c "$(declare -f printcmd); "'printcmd "$@"' _ \
  somecommand {} \;
```

Note that the string we're prepending to our `-exec` argument is precisely `bash -c "$(declare -f printcmd); "'printcmd "$@"' _` -- the `$(declare -f printcmd)` expands to the code for the function; after that, we *actually call* the function with arguments `$1` and onward, and put `_` as a placeholder for `$0`.

You can substitute `zsh` or `ksh` instead of bash, if you want output escaped for that shell.

Comment: With `zsh`: `find . -exec zsh -c 'print -r "${(q)@}"' zsh somecommand {} +`

Comment: With recent versions of `bash`, see also: `find . -exec bash -c 'echo -E "${@@Q}"' bash somecommand {} +` (assuming a `bash` where the `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are not enabled by default)

Comment: Since you're using Bash, `export -f printcmd`, and then `find . -exec bash -c 'printcmd "$@"' _ somecommand {} \;`

Comment: Actually, why bother with the function at all? Why not just `find . -exec bash -c 'printf "%q " "$@"; echo' _ somecommand {} \;` ?

Comment: @ilkkachu, the first why is to not break people who _aren't_ on bash. With Apple making zsh default recently, there are rather a lot of those. The second "why" is that functions are more flexible so I prefer them in general; one could split the code over multiple lines, add more functionality, and use any kind of quoting one wants without extra hassle. Better to showcase a flexible practice than a brittle one.